# How convert time interval in time points with a recursive query

Tags: sql-server-2008, recursion, recursive-query

I am trying, woking with SQL SERVER 2008, to create a function which returns a row for each time checkpoint countained in a given interval .
In other terms, given a table telling me that a certain object was active in a certain interval

```
[ID]   [TIME FROM]      [TIME TO]
23     12:34:00         13:14:00
```

I was trying to get, as a result set, a table like this:

```
[ID]   [TimeCheck]      [flag]
23     12:00:00        0  
23     12:15:00        0  
23     12:30:00        1  
23     12:45:00        1  
23     13:00:00        1  
23     13:15:00        0
```

which I can use to link to the table providing me the interval for each ID (see below at *finalgoal*)
The reason is that I'd like to calculate some statistics to create charts and I'd like to count the number of ID which checked at a given set of checkpoint times.
I could use a cursor, but that sounds quite a rough approach and I hoped someone could suggest something better.
I was thinking of CTE or recursive functions as this sounds an ideal recursive problem but I could not work it out

Thanks for your suggestions!
---- edit ---
of course I could use a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_GetTimePoints (@ID INT, @timeFrom TIME, @timeTo TIME ,@intervalMinutes INT)
RETURNS @result TABLE ( [ID] INT , LasTimeCheck TIME , flag BIT)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @curTick INT = DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'00:00:00',@timeFrom)/@intervalMinutes+1
DECLARE @endTick INT = DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'00:00:00',@timeTo)/@intervalMinutes
WHILE ( @curTick < = @endTick )
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @result
  SELECT @ID, DATEADD(MINUTE,@curTick*@intervalMinutes,0),1
  SET @curTick = @curTick + 1
END
RETURN
END
```

**The final goal** would be doing something like this:

```
select ID,TS_In,TS_end, A.* FROM VEH M LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM 
dbo.test_GetTimePoints(ID,M.ts_In,M.ts_end,15) )A ON A.ID=M.ID
```

which is obviously not working since I cannot give `ID,M.ts_In,M.ts_end,15` as parameters to the function.
Any idea to achieve the same results?

Comment: why don't you apply these first

Comment: Whats the output you'll like?

Comment: for the final output, I have added **The final goal** section

Comment: actually, later in development, I realized that I don't need the rows with flag 0, as I am not using them and would be just a drag in the communication with the webapplication which has to format the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a function the easiest way to do it would be to use [OUTER APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT ID,TS_In,TS_end, A.* 
  FROM VEH M 
 OUTER APPLY
 (
   SELECT * 
     FROM dbo.test_GetTimePoints(ID, M.ts_In, M.ts_end, 15) A
 ) A
```

But the function looks suspicious as it does not account for time outside the interval of objects' activity. You might change it to produce list of times only for some interval (a day?), do a cross join with VEH and mark time between start and end of a period of 15 minutes:

```
SELECT ID, TS_In, TS_end, 
       CASE WHEN M.TS_In <= dateadd (minute, 15, A.LastTimeCheck )
             AND M.TS_end >= A.LastTimeCheck
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END Flag
  FROM VEH M 
 CROSS JOIN dbo.test_GetTimePoints('07:00:00', '23:00:00', 15) A
```

To eliminate function alltogether, one would use recursive CTE to produce time table:

```
; WITH test_GetTimePoints (LastTimeCheck) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('07:00:00' as time)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(minute, 15, LastTimeCheck)
      FROM test_GetTimePoints
       WHERE LastTimeCheck < CAST ('23:00:00' as time)
)
SELECT ID, TS_In, TS_end, 
       CASE WHEN M.TS_In <= dateadd (minute, 15, A.LastTimeCheck )
             AND M.TS_end >= A.LastTimeCheck
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END Flag
  FROM VEH M 
 CROSS JOIN test_GetTimePoints A
```

**UPDATE:**

This query is like any other - you might send parameters from application, ie `@interval int` would do nicely. You could still use CTE variant, but you should filter out unwanted time:

```
; WITH test_GetTimePoints (LastTimeCheck) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('00:00:00' as time)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(minute, @interval, LastTimeCheck)
      FROM test_GetTimePoints
       WHERE LastTimeCheck < dateadd (minute, - @interval, 
                                      CAST ('00:00:00' as time))
)
SELECT ID, TS_In, TS_end
  FROM VEH M 
 CROSS JOIN test_GetTimePoints A
 WHERE M.TS_In <= dateadd (minute, @interval, A.LastTimeCheck )
   AND M.TS_end >= A.LastTimeCheck
-- Default = 100, but we need to produce up to 1440 records
-- So we turn the limit off with zero.
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Better solution would be to have a calendar table (in this case all minutes in a day) and use CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT ID,TS_In,TS_end, A.LastTimeCheck 
  FROM VEH M 
 OUTER APPLY
 (
   SELECT LastTimeCheck 
     FROM TimeTable A
    WHERE (datediff (minute, 0, LastTimeCheck) % @interval = 0)
      AND M.TS_In <= dateadd (minute, @interval, A.LastTimeCheck )
      AND M.TS_end >= A.LastTimeCheck
 ) A
```

TimeTable could be populated using CTE above with @interval set to one.

Comment: Nikola, that helped a lot- I didn't know about Outer apply.
The last code you put is nearly exactly what I'd like to do - the only problem is that I would like to replace the static times '07:00:00' and '23:00:00' with the times TS_in and TS_out from the matching record of table VEH.
The reason for this is that the active period is usually small compared to the whole day and the whole bunch of flag 0 ticks I would get should be filtered out. [moreover I want to give some flexibility to specify the timeInterval -as low as 5 mins] Is there a way to avoid them to be generated in first place?

Comment: Thanks Nikola,
I think I will go for the calendar table solution.
Still doubtful about the use of the CTE test_GetTimePoints: I know I can use parameters from the application, but what I wanted to do is to assign a different TS_in and TS_out which are varying depending on the record...  without using loops or cursors to set the external parameters. Do you know any way to do that?

Comment: @eddo Calendar table will allow you to use simple join which will probably be faster than apply. CTE cannot be defined inside query, only at the beginning, and cannot have parameters. No luck there. Only way to use it is as my first example in update section: let it generate all possible times, cross join to VEH and remove extras.

Comment: I suspected that but since WITH is not yet bread and butter for me I wanted some confirmation...
I will go for a Calendar table generated dynamically so that I am sure no one (me included) can mess around it.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_GetTimePoints
(
    @ID INT, 
    @timeFrom TIME, 
    @timeTo TIME,
    @intervalMinutes INT
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(
    WITH C (LasTimeCheck) AS
    (
      SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @intervalMinutes, @timeFrom)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @intervalMinutes, LasTimeCheck)
      FROM C
      WHERE LasTimeCheck < @timeTo
    )
    SELECT @ID AS ID,
           LasTimeCheck,
           1 AS flag
    FROM C         
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael, got the concept!